# How to add Visual Studio Code hotkey to start debugging with a specific launch config even if it's currently not the active one?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, debug

If I for example had 3 "Launch" configuration defined for PowerShell:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MyDebug1",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": "${file}",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "name": "MyDebug2",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": "${file}",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "name": "MyDebug3",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": "${file}",
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I know all these configurations are identical, I am just making a point.

Is possible to define a keyboard shortcut to start a debugging session with the launch config, `MyDebug3`, even if it's not the currently active launch config in **Run and Debug** panel?

The closest I can find is this option, [Ability to select and start a launch using keyboard](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_ability-to-select-and-start-a-launch-using-keyboard). I would much prefer a direct hotkey.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that's impossible by default and it was even [rejected](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/4615) as a feature.

You can use [Launch Configs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config) extension though. An example keybind that you add to JSON would then be:

```json
  {
    "key": "shift+ctrl+f1",                       
    "command": "launches.MyDebug3"
  }
```

where `MyDebug3` is the defined name from your `launches` setting, which the extension adds and you need to map to names from `launch.json`, e.g.:

```json
  "launches": {
    "MyDebug3": "MyDebug3",
  }
```

More options can be found in the description of the extension.

Comment: You are a life saver, as always. Thanks!